# Porting a Python JSON API to Java (GWT)

Tags: java, python, gwt, gson, porting

I am trying to port this bit of Python code to Java http://www.bemasher.net/archives/1002 (scroll down to the bottom for the code)

But because everything is dynamically typed, I'm having difficulty porting this. I need to be able to use a Java implementation of Pythons json. Right now I'm using gson ( http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ ), but I'm open to anything.

Neither of gson's *fromJson's* signatures

```
public <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT) throws JsonParseException
public <T> T fromJson(String json, Type typeOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException
```

match Pythons

```
data = json.loads(response)
```

This is the JSON that I am trying to read: http://www.ows.newegg.com/Stores.egg/Categories/1

How would I go about getting the class or type of the JSON above and read through it? All the other examples I've seen you have to know what it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically fetches `http://www.ows.newegg.com/Stores.egg/Menus` and dumps its contents to a string (`response`), then it parses the JSON using `json.loads()` and puts that into `data`.

Then it will iterate through the contents of data and build a HTML list using `lxml`. The list itself should look like:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/Store?{StoreID}">{StoreTitle}</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Where `{StoreID}` and `{StoreTitle}` are the IDs and titles fetched and parsed from that URL.

**References: [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html), [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html), [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/index.html#documentation)**

Comment: I understand this, but I can't figure out how to go about doing it with Gson. I'll get back to this tomorrow when I have a little more time! (I'll make the question a little more clear)

Comment: +1 for the answer - I've refactored my question and made it just about what I'm having a problem with and not so much background.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I was using Google Web Toolkit - sorry about that. I went ahead and accepted *@NullUserException* 's answer though I'm writing this for anyone else who may come across this.

When converting this from Python to the Java (GWT) equivalant, I found that there was already support in GWT for JSON, and even better it works on the client side saving trips to the server. (source: [JSON GWT API](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONObject.html))

To keep thoe code clean I am using a wrapper for it that can be found on Google Code [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-jsonwrapper/).